# jquery pass each element from selector to function, make array that choose last element

Tags: jquery, function, selector

I have some function declared like this that check element for something(true, false):

```
(function($) {
$.myfunc = function(element, settings) {
    // skiped return comparison
};

})(jQuery);
```

Then I want to use this function as an additional selector. I am trying sometime like this(of course its wrong code):

```
var lastprl = $("a[prl]").filter(function() { $.myfunc($(this), {param : 0}) }).last();
```

Seems the main idea is right to filter elements with my function, then select `.last()` from array. Please, help fix this code. Maybe I incorrectly use `$.myfunc` call? or something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.filter()` requires a return value from the function you give it. Your `return` is missing.

```
.filter(function() { return $.myfunc($(this), {param : 0}) })
        // ------------^^^
```

Also make sure `$.myfunc` is returning a boolean result.